# Can launch but not run my Nodelet

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Since few days I try to understand and use Nodelet to dynamically load process from a cpp Node. I read lots of questions and answer from this forum and I have a problem. (Btw thanks to the community with clear answers on many questions)

I just copied the code from nodelet_tutorial_math and modified it to republish with custom messages and I can launch my Node using this launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" args="manager" />
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="test_nodelet" 
    args="load test_nodelet/Add nodelet_manager">
  </node>
</launch>
```

But when I try to use the following commands:

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=nodelet_manager 
rosrun nodelet nodelet load test_nodelet/Add nodelet_manager __name:=test_nodelet
```

I can't run my nodelet because the manager does not find it in the nodelet package:

```
[ERROR] [1490717511.798024359]: Failed to load nodelet [/nodelet_test] of type [test_nodelet/Add] even after refreshing the cache: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class test_nodelet/Add with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/crop_foremost depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz_radial depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzi depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzi_radial depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/crop_nonZero image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_rotate/image_rotate image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus pcl/BAGReader pcl/BoundaryEstimation pcl/ConvexHull2D pcl/CropBox pcl/EuclideanClusterExtraction pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/ExtractPolygonalPrismData pcl/FPFHEstimation pcl/FPFHEstimationOMP pcl/MomentInvariantsEstimation pcl/MovingLeastSquares pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/NormalEstimation pcl/NormalEstimationOMP pcl/NormalEstimationTBB pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PFHEstimation pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/PrincipalCurvaturesEstimation pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/RadiusOutlierRemoval pcl/SACSegmentation pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals pcl/SHOTEstimation pcl/SHOTEstimationOMP pcl/SegmentDifferences pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VFHEstimation pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2
[ERROR] [1490717511.798075777]: The error before refreshing the cache was: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class test_nodelet/Add with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/crop_foremost depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz_radial depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzi depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzi_radial depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/crop_nonZero image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_rotate/image_rotate image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus pcl/BAGReader pcl/BoundaryEstimation pcl/ConvexHull2D pcl/CropBox pcl/EuclideanClusterExtraction pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/ExtractPolygonalPrismData pcl/FPFHEstimation pcl/FPFHEstimationOMP pcl/MomentInvariantsEstimation pcl/MovingLeastSquares pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/NormalEstimation pcl/NormalEstimationOMP pcl/NormalEstimationTBB pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PFHEstimation pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/PrincipalCurvaturesEstimation pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/RadiusOutlierRemoval pcl/SACSegmentation pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals pcl/SHOTEstimation pcl/SHOTEstimationOMP pcl/SegmentDifferences pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VFHEstimation pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2
```

My CMakeList is the following one:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_nodelet)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS nodelet roscpp std_msgs)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES nodelet_test
  CATKIN_DEPENDS nodelet roscpp std_msgs
)

add_library(nodelet_test src/test_nodelet.cpp)
target_link_libraries(nodelet_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
if(catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES)
  add_dependencies(nodelet_test ${catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES})
endif()

install(TARGETS nodelet_test
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
  
install(FILES nodelet_test.xml 
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

and here is my nodelet_test.xml:

```
<library path="lib/libnodelet_test">
  <class name="test_nodelet/Add" 
         type="test_nodelet::Add" 
         base_class_type="nodelet::Nodelet">
    <description> 
      test creating nodelet
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

I just don't get it... Why does it work with roslaunch but not when I try to run it manually ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258112/can-launch-but-not-run-my-nodelet/) by [bulgrozer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22356/bulgrozer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2017-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the error message from your launch, this seems to be similar to [this one](https://answers.ros.org/question/235339/failed-to-load-nodelet/?answer=235434#post-id-235434) where `nodelet` xml definition was the fix.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0